# Setting breakpoints in 2 different threads in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, ui-thread, background-thread

I want to set breakpoints in UI thread and Background thread. I put a breakpoint at the start of `run()` method in Background Thread and another break point at variable in UI thread, I want to examine. I set break point property to suspend all. Once I hit the break point at run() method in background thread, I am stepping over the code line by line. But I am unable to go to the UI thread by doing this.

Can some one explain how to examine values in both threads at the same time?

I am using Android Studio.

Comment: No, I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Debugging threaded code is always a bit of a pain. I would advise that you rather try to use some onscreen output of values for this purpose. Alternately use the android [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to output values.

Comment: I have faced this problem too. If I find a solution I will share it with you.